# Git SSH Key - not asking for SSH password

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I'm having trouble accessing my gitlab repo through SSH.

When trying the connection through below line I get authenticated.

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.<mydomain>
```

But when trying to access through the lines below its not prompting for my SSH password.

```
PS ~> git clone git@gitlab.<mydomain>:<repo name>.git      
Cloning into '<repo name>'...
git@gitlab.<mydomain>'s password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

The git remote -v seems to be correct:

```
origin  git@gitlab.<mydomain>:<repo name>.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.<mydomain>:<repo name>.git (push)
```

Any more ideas on how to authenticate through SSH?

Answer (score 0):

The first uses (Open)SSH's authentication scheme, which includes looking in the `~/.ssh` directory for known SSH keys.

The second uses Gitlab's SSH authentication scheme, which requires you to [add your public key through the Gitlab interface](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account). It should be somewhere under Account Settings->Security->SSH keys.

Comment: Yes, I have done that by coping the key through the terminal. So it should be correct.

Comment: But have you added your SSH keys through the Gitlab interface? That's usually accessed through a web browser. I'm not sure if there is any API provided to set SSH keys. I added a link to the Gitlab documentation explaining this step.

Comment: Yes I have added it under user settings -> SSH Keys