# git asks for SSH password instead of using SSH key

Tags: git, ssh

I set up an SSH server that contains a git repository. I have a user that can remotely connect to that ssh server using SSH keys (generated with `ssh-keygen` and then communicated to the server with `ssh-copy-id`), so that when I use the command `ssh git@serverIP` it connects without requiring the user to type the server password.

But when that same user tries to push to the repository with `git push` it asks for the server password, as if the user never shared the SSH key. I suppose I have to configure the git repository to use the SSH keys, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358787/git-ssh-key-not-asking-for-ssh-password) addresses in the case of gitlab repositories. Note that i'm not using GitHub either.

Using `git remote -v` gives:

```
origin git@serverIP:repository.git (fetch)
origin git@serverIP:repository.git (push)
```

My goal is to be able to execute a script that can push to the repository without needing user interaction, i.e. without asking the password. Any idea? Help would be much appreciated...

**Edit:**

Setting up again the repository actually fixed the problem. As a side note, when executing the script it still asked for the password: the problem was that I was executing the script with `sudo`, meaning that it was no longer the user to push to the repository, but root (that didn't have SSH keys). Hope this note can help someone else.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: This implies that you have two different URLs set up for the repository: the fetch URL uses ssh and the push URL doesn't. That would show up in `git remote -v` output.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I actually tried setting up again the repository and it now it works.

Comment: You can also consider [this cross-site Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26371/ssh-prompts-for-password-despite-ssh-authorized-keys#comment35605_26371) or [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password) [potential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)